# Faster math algorithm sacrificing accuracy

Tags: algorithm, math

I am developing a game that calls so many math functions for physics and rendering. ["Fast inverse sqrt"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) used in Quake3 is known to be faster than sqrt() and its background is beautiful.

Do you know any other algorithm that is faster than usual one with acceptable accuracy loss?

Comment: Maybe you also get answers for that on http://mathoverflow.net

Comment: I'm not sure if the fast inverse root used in Quake is faster these days than doing an RSQRTPS, and it does four in parallel. These days the cost of moving data from the FPU to RAM to register, manipulate, store and reload into the FPU might be more than just doing an FSQRT.

Comment: I should mention the usual advice about "measure before you optimise".  If your bottleneck turns out to be on the GPU rather than the CPU then a faster Sqrt in your physics code won't help you much.

Comment: The hack used in quake 3 is not fast anymore by today's standards. SSE instructions are just as fast if not faster.

Comment: The hack worked back then because there was no hardware available to do these things. Nowadays lighting is calculated on the GPU. If you're writing a software rasterizer, however, it can be still be useful, but I would look at the SSE instruction set first (_mm_rsqrt_ps does the trick).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These algorithms are called "approximation algorithms" in literature. The standard book with plenty of examples is [Approximation Algorithms by Vijay V. Vazirani](http://www.amazon.com/s?search-alias=stripbooks&field-isbn=3540653678).

The case of sin x ~~ x is a special case of something slightly more general: Look at the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) (or Fourier series in the case of periodic functions) of your function and compute only the first few terms.

Another (somewhat brutal) technique is to randomly assemble a few points of your function and then run a linear regression against it. That way, you can get a good polynomial describing your function, too :).

Comment: A linear regression will result in a 'straight line fit' - probably not what you want.  But you could fit a 2nd or 3rd degree polynomial in a least squared sense which may result in acceptable accuracy.

Comment: You can find the coeffecients of the polynomial with a linear regression.

Comment: I don't agree. Taylor series have poor properties outside a small area around the point they are computed at. Either you can manage to transform your function (eg. exp(x) = exp(x/2^n)^(2^n) makes you compute only exponentials around zero), or you have to do something else: minimax polynomial approximation (hard to compute (once), but accurate), or Chebyshev approximation (easy to compute, almost as accurate). You ensure that the accuracy is within controlled bounds **in the whole domain of interest**.

Answer (score 13):

Any continuous function (which includes most common math operations) can be well approximated over a bounded interval by a polynomial.  This, together with relatively simple identities that common math functions usually satisfy (like addition laws) and table lookups, provides the basis of the standard techniques to construct fast approximation algorithms (and also the basis of high accuracy methods like those used in the system math library).

Taylor series are usually a poor choice, however; Chebyshev or Minimax polynomials have much better error characteristics for most computational uses.  The standard technique for fitting minimax polynomials is to use Remes' Algorithm, which is implemented in a lot of commercial math software, or you can roll your own implementation with a day's work if you know what you're doing.

For the record, the "fast inverse square root" should be avoided on modern processors, as it is substantially faster to use a floating-point reciprocal square root estimate instruction (`rsqrtss`/`rsqrtps` on SSE, `vrsqrte` on NEON, `vrsqrtefp` on AltiVec).  Even the (non-approximate) hardware square root is quite fast on current Intel processors.

Answer (score 5):

for small x: sin(x) ~= x is one that is often used in physics

Answer (score 3):

Niko has some good suggestions to which I'd add the old fashion look up table.

I've used a look up table for circular functions (sin/cos/tan) successfully many times in high performance real time systesm.  The sqrt() is harder this way, but if your input range is restricted  (to say screen pixels) it's hard to beat for speed, and you can tune the space/accuracy trade off exactly.  You can also use the look up for a common range, and then have a fallout to a framework sqrt() function for the rare case.

Paul

Answer (score 2):

From the Doom source code, for approximate distance between two 2D points without having to use sqrt() or trigonometric functions:

```
fixed_t P_AproxDistance(fixed_t dx, fixed_t dy )
{
    dx = abs(dx);
    dy = abs(dy);
    if (dx < dy)
        return dx+dy-(dx>>1);
    else
        return dx+dy-(dy>>1);
}
```

Note that `x >> 1` is the same as `x / 2` but slightly faster - good modern compilers do this automatically nowadays but back then they weren't so great.

Comment: Okay, that took forever, but `fixed_t` is a typedef of `int`. So what are you approximating the distance of?

Answer (score 1):

Anything probabilistic is usually like this.  Running a simulation 10 times will be faster, but yield less accurate results than running a simulation 1000 times.